# Java How to write a string in file as bytes and get string back

Tags: java, string, file, utf-8

I need to write a string in a file as bytes in UTF-8 and then get these bytes back from file and convert it back to string and as a consiquence get the same string. May be it sounds easy but there is a hidden problem such as incorrect symbols in file. I mean that after appending in file it must contain something like:

> 00000008 d0bad0bb d18ed187 00000010 etc...

But it contains stuff like that:

> mystring  ---a lot of space---    (and the symbol that doesn't display here)

So, what have I already done? I've tried this way:

Before code read this: I keep strings in HashMap < String, String > that's why my code contains get(...) etc.

```
try {
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream("filename.txt");
        Set<String> keySet = storage.keySet();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        for (String key : keySet) {
            byte[] keyInByte = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] valueInByte = storage.get(key).getBytes("UTF-8");
            oStream.write(buffer.putInt(0, valueInByte.length).array());
            oStream.write(keyInByte);

            oStream.write((buffer.putInt(0, valueInByte.length).array()));
            oStream.write(valueInByte);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("permission denied");
    }
```

I have also tried use PrintWriter, FileWriter, etc... but it doesn't give what I need. For example, some of them need toString() method but after toString() I will lose the ability to work with bytes.

! Notice, that I've tried to change my notepad to UTF-8 encode, but it gives no result.

Comment: Why not use PrintWriter and BufferedReader as the file will always be bytes in the end anyway.  They will be simpler, and possibly faster.  Normally `.txt` means text not binary.  BTW DataInput/OuputStream as a writeUTF/readUTF method which does something like this more efficiently.

Comment: @PeterLawrey As I mentioned I've tried many ways including PrintWriter, it needs to use toString() method for my operations. So then I will loose the ability to work with bytes correctly.

Comment: Not sure why you can't do that with Reader/Writer. From your description it appears your problem is that you are using binary and not text. but if you need a binary format you can use data streams.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Could you write some code? May be there's a solution that I don't unserstand...

Comment: A specific example would depend on your requirements, for example, I wouldn't write the length in a text file, only in a binary file. Writing the length makes editing the file unreasonably harder to edit. (With a binary format editing the file is not an option)  It's also not clear to me if you want text or binary.  BTW You should always print out an exception as there could be many causes.

Comment: Another thing which has me confused is; why would you toString() a String.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok, as input I have 2 strings K and V, I must print K and V in file but as a sequence of bytes like `d18ed187`. And to get my string V by K from bytes from file I need to convert it back. But why do I need it if I have a HashMap where my string are displayed correctly? Yes, it's true but what if I turn off my programm and turn it on again? In this case my HashMap will be clear but "myfile.txt" will contain all the previous data! So to get this data I need to convert that from bytes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62705/discussion-between-maxim-gotovchits-and-peter-lawrey).

Comment: The requirement " I must print K and V in file but as a sequence of bytes " doesn't mean anything to me as all files are a sequence of bytes, there is no other choice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok, I meant it must be displayed as a sequence of bytes as it really is.

Comment: How do you need to make it work differently to how files work already?  When you look at a file you are displaying it as a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Are you expecting hexi-decimal to be used somewhere?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, there's a particular output as I mentioned. File must contain symbols like `d18ed187`. So yes, I expect hexadecimal output.

Comment: In that case, you need to convert the text to hexidecimal, not UTF-8. Do you have an actual example as `d0bad0bb d18ed187` is unprintable. i.e. it is not text in hexidecimal. This could be non-ASCII letters encoded as UTF-8 and then encoded into hexidecimal.  BTW If this is homework, you should really ask you teacher as there is no point trying to guess what they had in mind.

Comment: This is d0bad0bb http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d0ba/index.htm http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d0bb/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Properties you can do this.

```
new Properties(map).save(new FileOutputStream("filename.proeprties"));
```

to load the properties

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("filename.properties"));
map.putAll(prop);
```

To save copying the data you can use Properties as a Map.

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

Note: a key cannot contain a `=` or a newline.

---

This is how I would do it in a binary format

```
DataOutputStream dos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename.dat")));
dos.writeInt(map.size());
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    dos.writeUTF(entry.getKey());
    dos.writeUTF(entry.getValue());
}
dos.close();
```

---

This is how I would write it in text, using UTF-8

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOuputStream("filename.txt") "UTF-8"));
pw.println(map.size());
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
     pw.println(encode(entry.getKey()));
     pw.println(encode(entry.getValue()));
}
pw.close();


public static String encode(String s) {
    // if you can assume no new lines, don't do anything.
    return s.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\").replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");
}
```

This will produce a like like

```
key1
value1
key2
value2
```

This you can edit fairly easy.  If youc an assume the key doesn't have an `=` or `:` or tab, you can use one line like a properties file

Comment: Thank You! You really helped me. But I have one more question: `return s.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\").replaceAll("\n", "\\n");` doesn't work because of "\\" and "\\\\". Should I use "//" instead? BTW I use intellij IDEA on Windows 8.1 if that matters =) I'm sorry for stupid questions, I'm just new at Java.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Btw I have intellij on win 8.1 as well.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am guessing that "*doesn't work*" means "*throws exception*" because `replaceAll` uses regex as argument and `"\\"` is incorrect regex in Java (it is like writing ``\`` as regex which is wrong because ``\`` needs something after it like `\s` or `\d` or ``\\``). Maybe you wanted to use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`?

Comment: `replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\")` have no sense :/ (you are replacing one ``\`` with one ``\`` because ``\`` is also special in replacement part - it can be used with `"\\$"` to represent `$` literal because `$` itself is also special because it can be used like `"$1"` to let us use in replacement match stored in group 1). If you want to replace one ``\`` with two ``\\`` either use `replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\")` or to avoid regex confusion `replace("\\","\\\\")`.

Comment: Similarly `replaceAll("\n","\\n")` will not replace line separator `\n` with two characters: ``\`` and `n`, but only with `n`. Unless I misunderstood your intention you probably want to use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`

Comment: @Pshemo The first argument is a regex, the second is a string. I will have to test it.

Comment: Yes, second argument is string, but this argument is not just any string, because it also is used by regex engine while replacing, and can contain some special characters, which are `$` - reference to match from group matched by regex (for instance `$1` represents match from group 1), ``\`` to let us escape `$`, so to represent ``\`` literal in this second argument you need to write it as `"\\\\"`.

Comment: @Pshemo In that case the first replaceAll is wrong.

Comment: That was my point :). Anyway to avoid this regex magic we can use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` (it will automatically escape any special characters in *regex* and *replacement* arguments) which will let us rewrite above code in little more readable way like `replace("\\","\\\\").replace("\n","\\n")`.